# Delete Attributed Text When You Click on TextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm having trouble figuring out how to delete attributed text when a user clicks on a `textView`, much like it does when you do on a `textField`. I know how to assign the attributed text, but I want it to disappear when a user clicks on the `textView`, rather than having to delete the attributed text themselves.

Here is the code I'm using to populate:

```
 if([self.detailItem.comments.rootBeerComment isEqual: @""] || self.detailItem.comments.rootBeerComment == nil){
            NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Notes..."];
            self.rootBeerNotes.attributedText = string;
        }else{
            self.rootBeerNotes.text = self.detailItem.comments.rootBeerComment; 
        }
```

Comment: So, just delete all the text on click?

Comment: Yep. Same way when you set `attributedText` on a text field, and then click it it, the text disappears.

Comment: How about `textView.attributedText = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@""];`?

Comment: That's what I did to set it. But when I click in the textView, I have to delete what I set.

Comment: Are you using `UITextViewDelegate`?

Comment: No, I'm not using a delegate.

Comment: set attributedText property of UITextView to nil in textFieldShoudBeginEditing:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do something when the textView is tapped, you need to know when this event happens.  The easiest way is to set the delegate of the textView to your view controller, and then implement the `UITextViewDelegate` delegate method which tells you this:

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textView
{
    // You may need to check that it is the right textView if you have more than one.
    textView.attributedText = nil;
    return YES;
}
```

As an aside, you can replace this line of code:

```
if([self.detailItem.comments.rootBeerComment isEqual: @""] || self.detailItem.comments.rootBeerComment == nil){
```

with this one, which is shorter and does the same thing since the length of an empty string and the length of a nil object will both return 0:

```
if([self.detailItem.comments.rootBeerComment length] == 0){
```

Comment: I added the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` method you described and made my view controller a delegate for the view, but it isn't working. What am I missing?

Comment: set a breakpoint inside the method and see if it is being called.  If not, then the delegate probably isn't being setup correctly.

Comment: As a note, the method should be `textViewShouldBeginEditing`, rather than `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this.  Make an NSRange that is from the first to the last character and use an empty string "".

myAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in range: NSRange, with str: String)